# Ezra 10:3 --"According to the Law"

Tags: intermarriage, ezra-nechemya

[Ezra 10:3 says](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16507#),

> And now, let us make a covenant with our God to cast out all the wives
>   and their offspring, by the counsel of the lord and those who hasten
>   to [perform] the commandment of our God, and **according to the Law it
>   shall be done.**
>   וְעַתָּה נִכְרָת בְּרִית לֵאלֹהֵינוּ לְהוֹצִיא כָל
>   נָשִׁים וְהַנּוֹלָד מֵהֶם בַּעֲצַת אֲדֹנָי וְהַחֲרֵדִים בְּמִצְוַת
>   אֱלֹהֵינוּ וְכַתּוֹרָה יֵעָשֶׂה׃

[Rashi says](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16507#showrashi=true)

> **and according to the Law it shall be done:** he who performs this act, who will cast out his gentile wife and children.

I'm not clear if this means that the law says this is what is to be done, or if it means that is shall be done in the way the law says to do it?

Either way, does anyone know where the law addresses this?

Comment: You changed "the Lord" (from the Judaica Press translation (the one on `chabad.org`)) to "YHWH", but the verse doesn't have the tetragrammaton.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the correction and for the link.  Also related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40260/was-intermarriage-permissible-at-the-time-of-tanakh/41282#41282  There are no answers.  Does this serve the community better up and linked as a dup, or should I delete it?

Comment: FYI, "the Lord" was capitalized in the translation.  I did not think to look for it in the Hebrew.  Sorry.

Comment: (re your comment) Dupes are valuable because they can be searched for and searchers will be redirected to the other question. (re your other comment) The word does refer to God -- just not using the tetragrammaton.

Comment: Ah! so there is no distinction between when it is used for the tetragramaton or when it is used the Hebrew word for Lord in reference to God.  Re dupes:  Ok, I will leave as is then.  Thanks